# Is there a way to set environment variables based on branch in a Declarative Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm hoping to find a way to remove duplicated stages in a Declarative Jenkinsfile by loading environment variables based on the branch.

Currently I have something like:

```
@Library("MySharedLibrary@v1") _

String tagBaseDev = "repo.org/myspace/image:dev"
String tagBaseTest = "repo.org/myspace/image:test"
String tagBaseProd = "repo.org/myspace/image:prod"

pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    // Always Run This
    stage ('Maven Build and Unit Tests') {
      agent {label 'docker-slave'}
      steps {
        sharedLibraryBuild mavenGoals:'clean package', additionalProps:['ci.env':'']
        stash 'artifacts'
      }
    }
    // Dev Only
    stage ('Build Dev Docker Image and Push') {
      when {
        branch 'dev'
      }
      agent {label 'docker-slave'}
      steps {
        unstash 'artifacts'
        sharedLibraryDockerImageBuildPush tag:"$tagBaseDev"
      }
    }
    // Test Only
    stage ('Build Test Docker Image and Push') {
      when {
        branch 'test'
      }
      agent {label 'docker-slave'}
      steps {
        unstash 'artifacts'
        sharedLibraryDockerImageBuildPush tag:"$tagBaseTest"
      }
    }
    // Prod Only
    stage ('Build Prod Docker Image and Push') {
      when {
        branch 'prod'
      }
      agent {label 'docker-slave'}
      steps {
        unstash 'artifacts'
        sharedLibraryDockerImageBuildPush tag:"$tagBaseProd"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to be able to reduce that into one stage block and dynamically load in the needed `$tagBaseXXX` based on branch.  This is just an example but I'm planning to have four or five variables that will have different values for each environment.

My thought was to create `EnvDev`, `EnvTest`, and `EnvProd` maps with corresponding values and then create a `EnvMap` which is a Map that correlates the branch name to Environment Map.  For instance:

```
def EnvDev = [
  url: "dev.com",
  tag: "dev",
  var: "Dev Var"
]

def EnvProd = [
  url: "prod.com",
  tag: "prod",
  var: "prod Var"
]

def EnvMap = [
  dev: EnvDev,
  prod: EnvProd
]
```

I then try to create a Shared Library call that looks something like this:

```
def call(String branch, Map envMapping) {
    Map use_me = envMapping.get("${branch}")
    String url = use_me.get("URL")
    echo ("${url}")
}
```

With the idea being to pass the Map and pull the corresponding environment map based on the branch and then use the variables as needed.

So I have something like this:

```
@Library("MySharedLibrary@v1") _

def EnvDev = [
  url: "dev.com",
  tag: "dev",
  var: "Dev Var"
]

def EnvProd = [
  url: "prod.com",
  tag: "prod",
  var: "prod Var"
]

def EnvMap = [
  dev: EnvDev,
  prod: EnvProd
]

pipeline {
  agent {label 'docker-slave'}
  stages {
    stage ('Test Env Vars') {
      steps {
        echo "$env.GIT_BRANCH"
        sharedLibrarySetupEnv branch: "$env.GIT_BRANCH", evnMapping: EnvMap
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: setupEnv.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[branch:dev, env_mapping:[dev:[url:dev.com, tag:dev, var:Dev Var], ...]]]
>
> Possible solutions: call(java.lang.String, java.util.Map), wait(), any(), wait(long), main([Ljava.lang.String;), each(groovy.lang.Closure)

Is there an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

This is my first time trying to write a Shared Library function so I'm guessing it may just be some Groovy syntax/concept I'm not familiar with.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with how I was trying to invoke the Shared Library function.  I thought I was able to reference the variable names which led to the Jenkinsfile/pipeline passing a `LinkedHashMap` to the shared library and not two separate variables.

There are two solutions to this:

1. Have the Shared Library call method take in a `Map<String, Object> parms` and within the call reference the variables with `parms.varname`.

**Shared Library:**

```
def call(Map<String, Object> parms) {
    echo "${parms.branch}"
    Map use_this_map = parms.envMapping.get(branch)
}
```

**Jenkinsfile:**

```
setupEnv branch: "$env.GIT_BRANCH", envMapping: EnvMap
```

2. Don't pass the variable names in the Jenkinsfile and have the Shared Library call method take in corresponding variables.

**Shared Library:**

```
def call(String branch, Map<String, Map> envMapping) {
    echo "${branch}"
    Map use_this_map = envMapping.get(branch)
}
```

**Jenkinsfile:**

```
setupEnv $env.GIT_BRANCH, EnvMap
```

Answer (score 2):

your function signature is `def call(String branch, Map envMapping)`, but your calling is `branch: xxx, env_mapping:xxx`.

Change to `sharedLibrarySetupEnv branch: "$env.GIT_BRANCH", envMapping: EnvMap`

Comment: Sorry... Error when writing up the original post.  I will edit to reflect this change.  I'm still seeing the same behavior:

`hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: sharedLibrarySetupEnv.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[branch:dev, envMapping:[dev:[url:dev.com, tag:dev, var:Dev Var], ...]]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variable BRANCH_NAME and put it in a condition like below:-

```
if (env.BRANCH_NAME == master)
{
    //set all the environment variable you need
} else {
    //variable required if the condition doesn't match
}
```

You can use **REGEX** in the condition.

Comment: This would work in a Scripted Jenkinsfile or within a Script block in a Declarative Jenkinsfile but I was hoping to find a way to make it cleaner instead of having multiple if/else blocks in every stage.

Comment: yes, but you can create a function and call it in different stages rather then specifying the same block in every stage